# can't connect to socket io in production

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

I can't connect to socket.io in production. It works fine in my dev server, but I'm not getting the "websocket user connected" message in the console in production and my heat map isn't populating with the test data. I'm getting net:: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in the browser jscript console.

from the server:

```
io.origins('http://example.com/path:8080')

    app.get('/somepath', function (req, res, next) {
        // code here

        io.emit('update', data)
        console.log('update has been emitted') // this prints and I see the data object in the console
        res.end("OK")
    })

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('websocket user connected')
});
```

from the angular controller:

```
$http.get('http://example.com/somepath?'+str) // hits somepath with test data in query string 'str'
```

from the script in /path:

```
var socket = io('http://example.com:8080');
```

and I've also included the cdn for socket.io in the page /path

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @Alexander how would I do that? this is a remote ubuntu server and I know I set the ip tables to route port 8080 to 80. Is that what you mean? Because I can access the webpage and other html pages on the site, but I can't make websocket connection.

Comment: If your web socket is bound to internal port 8080, and your iptables route external port 8080 traffic to port 80, the request won't reach socket.io, it will only reach webserver. Try having same environment set-up as your dev server.

Comment: @Alexander I have the same set up as my dev server. The port was 3002 for all of them. I'm not sure what you mean "If your web socket is bound to internal port 8080, and your iptables route external port 8080 traffic to port 80, the request won't reach socket.io, it will only reach webserver." I set external traffic to route to 80 which I believe is the default port for HTTP traffic, but I never set anything in the iptables specifically for websockets. Do I need to designate another port to route anything with ws protocol to?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had to include to port number in the URL for the development server, but it will not make the connection if I use the port in my production server. I'm not sure exactly why this is, but I suppose that the port is implied in a request from my browser and maybe something about the format makes it unrecognizable if explicitly stated.

Changes I made:

I removed the io.origins statement from the server because the default for socket.io is to allow any origin. That removes one possible source of error.

I removed the port number from $http.get() in the angular controller and changed `var socket = io('http://example.com:8080') to var socket = io('http://example.com')` in another script